# ORMLite get Could not get next result for class Error

Tags: android, ormlite

i'm using ORMlite library in android and i get this error random and i dont know whats that and how to modrate:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not get next result for class [Ljava.lang.String;
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.next
```

i get this error when i'm using this method to get single column :

```
    public static List getSingleColumn(String query) {
        List<String> columnes = null;
        try {
            columnes = G.CATEGORY.queryRaw(query, new RawRowMapper<String>() {
                @Override
                public String mapRow(String[] columnNames, String[] resultColumns) throws android.database.SQLException {
                    return resultColumns[0];
                }
            }).getResults();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return columnes;
    }
```

or this code:

```
List unread_messages = G.DBHELPER.getSingleColumn("SELECT SUM(read_status) FROM messageslist");
```

Comment: In the future please provide the full exception.  The caused by section usually has good information about what is going on.

Comment: @Gray what is the actual reason for this error

Comment: I'm not sure without the full exception @avezraj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change method to this:

```
public static String getSingleColumn(String query) {
    String columnes = null;
    try {
        columnes = G.CATEGORY.queryRaw(query, new RawRowMapper<String>() {
            @Override
            public String mapRow(String[] columnNames, String[] resultColumns) throws android.database.SQLException {
                return resultColumns[0];
            }
        }).getFirstResult();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return columnes;
}
```